# Is there a Google Data API (gdata) for Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gdata-api

I would like to use [Google Data API](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) but I'm using Python 3. I didn't see that they mention anything about Python 3. Is it possible to install gdata for Python 3?

Comment: Have you tried running it through 2to3.py?

Comment: I did run it through 2to3, plus some manual changes. May well not work, but if you want to build on it: http://code.google.com/r/takowl-gdata-py3k/source/list

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, but given that it's all based around exchanging xml-formatted messages, you can easily use it at this lower level from Python 3.

Comment: You mean, I can download gdata and use it in Python 3?

Comment: No, I mean it's a protocol, you just need an xml library to use it. On top of that, Google also provides a library, which as far as I know is not compatible with Python 2.x. But you don't have to use that to take advantage of Google Data API.

Answer (score 1):

The gdata client is just a wrapper around the basic XML/http protocol that is used. You can use the basic protocol instead.

But it's probably easier to port gdata to Python 3, though. Contact the authors.

Answer (score 0):

Via [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8631469/161366), someone has created a python module for the spreadsheets API that does work with Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can just [`pip3 install google-api-python-client`](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client) and you'll have it. ;)

Comment: That does not install `gdata`, but [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client).

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.x version:
`pip install -e git+https://github.com/dvska/gdata-python3#egg=gdata`