# How can I read and edit Google Spreadsheets using Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets

I know I can read and edit Google Spreadsheets with [gdata](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/), but there is no gdata version for Python 3. Is there a (not really really complicated) way to edit Google Spreadsheet even though I want to use Python 3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Google Data API (gdata) for Python 3.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885882/is-there-a-google-data-api-gdata-for-python-3-x)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've authored an alternative [Python library for Google Spreadsheets](https://github.com/burnash/gspread). It supports Python 3 and has a less verbose API. You're welcome to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no, not yet. Well, except for exporting it as CSV, using Python on that, and uploading it again. But I guess that's not quite what you're after.

I started porting GData to Python 3. I think I got further than a previous effort, but it's not yet passing all the tests. You're welcome to give it a try, but you might have to make some changes to get it working:

http://code.google.com/r/takowl-gdata-py3k/source/list

Let me know if it works for you.