# Using Python to write to Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, gdata, gspread

I want to take data from a a website using Python, and write it onto the Google Sheets that I own. I searched for a way to do this for like an hour, but can't really find it. I found `gdata` and `gpsread` but they both look like they're outdated unless you have a Google Developer account. I may be wrong though.

Can someone tell me a way to do what I'm trying to do without a Google Developer account?

I don't really want to buy one, but if it's the only option, I might.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read and edit Google Spreadsheets using Python 3.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886052/how-can-i-read-and-edit-google-spreadsheets-using-python-3-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) seems to be actively maintained and looks like it works using only standard Google credentials.

Comment: I found that also but it looks like it's outdated. See below, which is from the website

Comment: import gspread

# Login with your Google account
gc = gspread.login('thedude@abid.es', 'password')

# WARNING: The code above uses ClientLogin and was disabled 
# on April 20, 2015.

Comment: The very next line tells you to use OAuth2 instead, and [provides instructions on how to do so](https://github.com/burnash/gspread#authorization-using-oauth2).

Comment: I know, but doesn't that require a developers account?

Comment: Ah yes, so it does. I'm pretty sure they're free, though, the charges associated are only for running code on AppEngine.

Comment: there's a 2 month trial, but I want this for the long term